# Custom PHP input and results in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Wondering if this is in anyway possible.. I want to pull information from a SQL database (other than the Joomla DB) and display it

Is this in anyway possible in Joomla. I thought of using a form tag with would POST / GET data to the browser and have a php script on the target page using the input information to display a result but because you cannot access Joomla pages directly this seems to be a mission.

Is there an easier way of doing this. Maybe an plugin or component?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Just want to see if it is a viable option

Comment: You may be better off asking this on the [new Joomla StackExchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) which just went into Beta.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by " you cannot access Joomla pages directly"? You have the access to the article.php file and other component files. You can also write a small module that would implement a php code, that you could include in any article.

However if your goal is to display an information from a different DB, why don't you use a simple AJAX request which would call a new php file? The new php file could access the secound DB without having load the Joomla libs and "print" all the info you need.